# Partial wake lock is not working

Tags: android, wakelock

My application is having `activities` and background `service` which has to run **24*7**,

My application has to talk to the server via `Wi-Fi` to send and receive the information.

**Problem:** whenever any alarm send by the server my app should receive and pops up the app whether it is running in foreground or background and intimate to the user about the alarm.

So when device is in active state this feature working perfectly but when device goes to sleep mode, after 1 or 2 mins it disconnects from the server and stop communicating. so in order to resolve it I written code which will set the WiFi sleep policy to NEVER and acquire the partial lock in the `OnCreate()` method of Background service and releasing the lock in `OnDestroy()` method of the service.Now observation is for some time it is working fine means for **5 or 10 mins** thereafter again it stop communicating.

App is developed on *Android 2.1* and deployed on device supports *Android 2.3* version.

I am not able to understand why partial lock behaves like this, please help me to resolve this issue.

regards,
Piks.

Comment: have you set WAKE_LOCK permission in manifest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem and finally found the solution which works perfectly.

Try to acquire the wake lock by extending Application class:
Code:

```
package com.example.MyApp.UserView;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.provider.Settings;

/**
 * @author SDurai
 * 
 */
public class MyApp extends Application 
{
    private static final String TAG = MyApp.class.getSimpleName();
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        if (mWakeLock.isHeld())
            mWakeLock.release();
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other doubts. Ready to help!

Comment: Manifest how did you called it ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Answer (score 3):

You probably need a WifiManager.WifiLock, too:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wl = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "myId");
wl.acquire();
```

(where wl is your WifiManager.WifiLock, which s)

Comment: I probably need? WHY?